# Scala parser gets stuck in infinite loop

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to write a simple parser in scala but when I add a repeated token Scala seems to get stuck in an infinite loop...

```
object RewriteRuleParsers extends RegexParsers {
  private def space = regex(new Regex("[ \\n]+"))
  private def number = regex(new Regex("[0-9]+")) 
  private def equals = (space?)~"="~(space?)
  private def word   = regex(new Regex("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*")) 
  private def string = regex(new Regex("[0-9]+")) >> { len => ":" ~> regex(new Regex(".{" + len + "}")) }  

  private def matchTokenPartContent: Parser[Any] = (space?)~word~equals~word<~ space?  
  private def matchTokenPart: Parser[Any] = ((space?) ~> "{" ~> matchTokenPartContent <~ "}"<~ space?)  
  private def matchTokenParts = (matchTokenPart *)  
  private def matchToken: Parser[Any] = ("[" ~> matchTokenParts ~ "]")

  def parseMatchToken(str: String): ParseResult[Any] = parse(matchToken, str)
}
```

and the code to call it

```
val parseResult = RewriteRuleParsers.parseMatchToken("[{tag=hello}]")
```

Any advice gratefull received

Comment: Note that e.g. `regex(new Regex("[0-9]+"))` can be written `"[0-9]+".r` (or just `"\\d+".r"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the precedence of `?`. Take the following, for example:

```
object simpleParser extends RegexParsers {
  val a = literal("a")
  val b = literal("b")
  def apply(s: String) = this.parseAll(a <~ b?, s)
}
```

The `a <~ b?` here is interpreted as `(a <~ b)?`, so it will accept `"ab"` or `""`, but not `"a"`. We'd need to write `a <~ (b?)` if we want it to accept `"a"`.

In your case you can just parenthesize `space?` at the end of `matchTokenPartContent` and `matchTokenPart` and it'll work as expected.

Comment: In fact, post-fixed operators are restricted now in 2.10. This can be more clearly and easily writte as `a <~ b.?`.